# 0 - конец программы, 1 - продолжить, как сделать?

Tags: java

в общем, я написал мини калькулятор и мне нужно чтобы в конце когда вводишь 0 программа заканчивалась, а 1 повторялась. Я пробовал добавить if (command == 1) но дальше без понятия

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("first number: ");
        int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("second number: ");
        int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Operation?: ");
        String operation = scanner.next();

        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.print("Ответ: ");
            System.out.println(num1 + num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
            System.out.print("Ответ: ");
            System.out.println(num1 - num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("*")) {
            System.out.print("Ответ: ");
            System.out.println(num1 * num2);

        } else if (operation.equals("/")) {
            System.out.print("Ответ: ");
            System.out.println(num1 / num2);

        }else {
            System.out.println("Error! ");
        }
        System.out.println("0-выход, 1-продолжение");
        int command = scanner.nextInt(); //вот здесь, как это оформить?
        


    }
    }
```

Comment: Всю программу в command=1; while(command) { .... } оберните. Выйдет только по 0

Comment: Не успел поправить while(command!=0). И еще после scanner.nextInt(); добавлять scanner.nextLine();

Comment: @Виктор, `scanner.nextLine` в данном случае добавлять НЕ надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможна такая реализация:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int command = 1;
while(command != 0)
{
    System.out.println("first number: ");
    int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    .....
    System.out.println("0-выход, 1-продолжение");
    command = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: `scanner.nextLine` добавлять НЕ надо, если внутри нигде не используется `scanner.nextLine()` для чтения строковых данных.

Comment: scanner.nextInt() - хитро работает, "съедает" конц строки, а scanner.nextLine() - перезапускает сканер

Comment: что значит "scanner.nextLine() перезапускает сканер"??  И `nextInt()` ничего "съедать" не будет, а совсем наоборот -- этот метод прочитает целое число до первого пробельного символа, _включая_ перевод строки, который останется в потоке.

Comment: "который останется в потоке" - вот его и удаляем. Имелось ввиду, что последующие ввод корректно отработал

Comment: Зачем, если для чтения данных используются `next() / nextInt()`, которые и так игнорируют перевод строки?

Comment: Если не будет этой строки и идёт nextInt() два раза подряд - то введя в первом nextInt() два значения - мы автоматом вводим данные и во второй nextInt() - согдаситеь - это как-то не хорошо. Возьмите зту прогу и поэкспериментируйте - увидите всё сами

Comment: Что значит _введя в первом nextInt() два значения - мы автоматом вводим данные и во второй nextInt()_??  Где гарантии что пользователь будет вводить числа, нажимая `Enter`?  Если бы так было, следовало бы тогда считывать строку ввода и парсить ее `int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());`

Comment: Всё реализовано, лишь как ответ на вопрос - смотрите вопрос и исходник. У меня не было задачи переписать программу